# Showing top 2 levels in main menu

Tags: menu, tabs

I am looking for a way to display 2 hierarchy levels in the main menu or some sort of tabbed menu.

Let me explain:
I have a site in 3 sections (I will not use subdomains), each with a hierarchy below.
Therefore on the homepage, the 3 sections should appear in the main menu.
On the top level page of a section (or the section homepage) the 3 sections should also be shown, but with the current section highlighted.  Below the sections, it should show a menu of the items in the section.  Al in the main menu
On any page in a section, the current section should appear highlighted and the top level of the hierarchy in the section should be shown. (and the current branch in the hierarchy should be highlighted).

I hope some image will help the explanation:
[menu in 2 levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX4dB.png)

[hierarchy with green blocks for homepage and section homepages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E81xE.png)

I will be using the avada theme, (and as a non-technical person) any suggestions on how I can easily tweak the menu will be appreciated.
I do not mind using a plugin if that helps.

Comment: Or if someone could suggest a way how to keep a mega menu open by default, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Is this possible?